# Google eCommerce tracking from PHP

Tags: php, ecommerce, tracking

Is some way to send eCommerce tracking to Google without JavaScript? I want to do that just with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/). Google already provides a PHP API for eCommerce tracking.